# Is there any way of changing the relative path of a mjs file (to make it see a different node_modules folder)?

Tags: node.js, mjs

When I'm executing pure node.js scripts I can change the path where it searches for `node_modules` as the following:

```sh
export NODE_PATH="/home/user/node_modules"
node "/home/user/different/path/file.js"
```

This way, I can make scripts located inside `/home/user/different/path/` see the `node_modules` folder located in `/home/user/` when they are executed.

So far everything is fine, the problem starts with `.mjs` files. If I try running:

```sh
export NODE_PATH="/home/user/node_modules"
node "/home/user/different/path/file.mjs"
```

I'll receive the error `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]` for the modules that I use in my code. The workaround that I know for that is creating a symbolic link inside my script's folder. Something like:

```sh
ln -s "/home/user/node_modules" "/home/user/different/path/node_modules"
```

After doing that, if I run `node "/home/user/different/path/file.mjs"` it'll work as expected and I'll be able to use libraries installed on `/home/user/node_modules` with the `import` statement in my script. However, I'd like to find a solution that doesn't require me to create a symbolic link of the `node_modules` folder. Is there any alternative solution when I'm working with `.mjs` files that allows me to change its relative path?